# issue with docker file for .net 5.0 core web api project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core 5.0 application template from visual studio weatherforecast core web api project

my docker file is :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetcoreapp.dll"]
```

> docker : The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - docker build -t mytestdocker:test .
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The command 'cm...on-zero >code: 1:String) [], RemoteException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>   ```

I am getting this error pls help

also share a .net core 5.0 valid and usable docker file inputs.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use dockerfile like in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66625666/13092211). This dockerfile for multi-project in 1 solution. You can configure your own requirements. I think your issue is wrong base image. Use .net 5.0 images for build and publish.